# Estimating inner and outer boundaries of habitable zone for Sun

Tags: habitable-zone, albedo

What would the inner and outer boundaries of the “habitable zone” be for planets with an albedo that differs from that of the Earth?

For example a planet with an albedo of 0.07 or 0.90 (the values for Mercury and Venus, respectively).

I want to compare these values to the distances in AU's of the rocky inner planets.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Homework question

Comment: Homework is not necessarily off topic. However the OP should improve their question by rephrasing as a question, not a demand; and include clear evidence of the effort that they have made to solve this themselves. For example, they could link to the websites that they have visited that show how the habitable zone of the sun is calculated. Otherwise this question is likely to be deleted.

Comment: Hints:  1) establish a *reason* for needing light (and/or energy) from a star in the first place. 2) establish a justification for suface albedo corresponding to energy being re-radiated into space.    This is the sort of question which could easily blow up into a full-scale biology study as well as a geology study.